# Rolling median by group

Tags: r, statistics, rolling-computation

I know variations of this question have been asked and answered 1,000 times. I've read every post and tried to implement what I read without success.

I have a dataframe of basketball individual game statistics for multiple players. I want to calculate 1) the "season to date" rolling median for each player (excluding the current observation) and 2) The median for he last 3 previous games (excluding the current observation)

I've included samples of what I would expect the output to be in each case.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
# Create Dataframe
plyr_seas = c("J.J. Redick", "Andre Drummond", "Daniel Theis", "Andre Drummond", "Daniel Theis", "J.J. Redick", "Andre Drummond", "J.J. Redick", "Andre Drummond", "J.J. Redick", "Daniel Theis", "Andre Drummond", "J.J. Redick", "Daniel Theis")

plyrOREBpmin_gm = c(0, 0.1715686275, 0.1013513514, 0.02721088435, 0.2002224694, 0, 0.1217861976, 0.03552397869, 0.1044386423, 0.03984063745, 0.03573555688, 0.2264150943, 0, 0.03719776813)

plyrGmsPlydpcs = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3)

expected_last_3_median = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.1217861976, 0, NA, 0.1044386423, 0.03552397869, 0.1013513514)

expected_overall_median = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.1715686275, 0.1013513514, 0, 0.0993897559, 0, 0.1217861976, 0, 0.1507869104, 0.1131124199, 0.01776198934, 0.1013513514)

Pbox = data.frame(plyr_seas, plyrOREBpmin_gm, plyrGmsPlydpcs, expected_last_3_median, expected_overall_median)
```

SOLUTION for above data! Provided by:  G. Grothendieck

```
# Calc rolling median for last three games (excluding current)
Pbox = Pbox %>% 
 group_by(plyr_seas) %>% 
 mutate(plyrOREBrateMdnLst3 = 
   rollapplyr(plyrOREBpmin_gm, list(-seq(3)), median, fill = NA))

# Calc rolling median for season to date (excluding current)
Pbox = Pbox %>% 
  group_by(plyr_seas) %>% 
  mutate(plyrOREBrateMdnSeas = 
    rollapplyr(plyrOREBpmin_gm, seq_along(plyrGmsPlydpcs), 
      function(x) median(head(x, -1)), fill = NA))
```

Comment: You are using `lag` incorrectly.  Suggest you use `rollapplyr(x, list(-seq(3)), median, fill = NA)` if you are trying to get the median of the prior 3 values.  `list(-seq(3))` means use offsets -1, -2 and -3, i.e. the 3 prior positions.  Also please follow the rules and only post reproducible code.  That means all library statements and inputs must be provided and show expected output.  Cut it down to a smaller example if your data is large.

Comment: G. Grothendieck, thanks for your response. I have revised the question as you suggested! Please have another look and let me know your thoughts!

Comment: Also, G. Grothendieck, If I use the code: Pbox = Pbox %>% group_by(plyr_seas) %>% mutate(plyrOREBrateMdnLst3 = rollapplyr(plyrOREBpmin_gm, list(-seq(3)), median, fill = NA))...I get the result I am expecting for pulling the rolling median of the last three games. Now I need to pull the rolling median for all games season to date.

Comment: This takes the median of all prior values excluding the current value: `rollapplyr(x, seq_along(x), function(x) median(head(x, -1)), fill = NA)`

Comment: G. Grothendieck, you sir. Are a saint, a scholar, and a gentleman. Thank you very much. This worked perfectly. I can't believe how much time I wasted on this. I have been wrestling it on and off for weeks now. I don't know how to check off that your answers were the working ones. For anyone who wants to know the final code that worked for the sample data has been pasted back into the edited initial question.

Comment: If you indent each code line by 4 spaces SO will format it for you. I have done it for you this time.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck post it as an answer ?

Comment: The poster has already posted it in the question so I don't think it is needed at this point.  You can upvote the question if you wish.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck. How do I alter this code to include the current value?

Comment: rollapplyr(x, k, fun, fill = NA) will use the last k values including the current value.

Comment: Really appreciate it. Thanks!